# How can I hack in health?

Tags: candy-box-2

I know to use the "Save game as text" button and I found the "number playerHp" part. I typed in my desired amount (2000) and loaded it in the game but it doesn't work. How can I hack it in?

Answer (score 1):

`playerHp` is your current health, not the maximum possible health. Your maximum health is determined by how many candies you have eaten. There are a few variables that seem to deal with this:

```
number gameCandiesEatenAccumulated=0, 
number gameCandiesEatenCurrent=0, 
number gameCandiesEatenMax=0
```

However, just by modifying `gameCandiesEatenCurrent` I was able to boost my hp. Remember: you'll need to add a lot of candies to boost your health significantly!

Comment: Then what is the maximum amount of health possible just by eating candies?

Answer (score 1):

You can also turn up the 'gameGiftHealth=0;' to 'gameGiftHealth=2000;'
That is what I do. It is also located almost right above the 'number playerHp'

Answer (score 0):

To increase your max health and health regeneration, you can do one or more of the following things:

- Change your number of candies eaten (*gameCandiesEatenCurrent*)
  *The maximum amount of health you can obtain from doing this is 900, up to a total of 1000 health, which is achieved by "eating" 3000000 candies. Any further candies eaten up to 2.5E9 candies will increase your health regeneration up to 500 HP/s, and any further candies eaten after that will have no effect. However, you can always change playerHp to your maximum possible HP for instant max healing.*
- Change gameGiftHealth 
  *Changing gameGiftHealth will add 200 health to your maximum health for each gameGiftHealth; for example, changing gameGiftHealth to 2500 will add 500000 to your maximum health.*
- Obtain the heart plug and heart pendant 
  *Each item will increase your maximum health by 20% (getting both increases it by 44%) - look for gridItemPossessedHeartPlug and gridItemPossessedHeartPendant and change both to true*